# Wrong CheckBoxPreference title color on kitkat device using AppCompat22

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, textcolor, checkboxpreference

I have an issue with the title color of CheckBoxPreference in my settings screen.
I am using AppCompat with appcompat-v7:22.2.0.

On a Lollipop device, no issue. AppCompat lib works as expected, that is, CheckBoxPreference title  is painted in textColorPrimary.

But on a kitkat device, CheckBoxPreference title is painted in textColorSecondary color instead of textColorPrimary color.

My color set up is :

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

In fact I have doubts now about CheckBoxPreference being "Material Design backward compatible".

Could you please confirm that it is backward compatible ? 
Any idea, workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the item below?
`<item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>`

It seems to work but I'm not sure if it's the right solution.